# Cálculo de percentagem

Tags: c

Alguém sabe me dizer se estou calculando a percentagem correta?

```
13. Um dado é lançado 50 vezes, sendo anotado o valor correspondente a cada
jogada. Faça um programa para:
(a) anotar os valores de todas as jogas em um vetor;
(b) determinar e imprimir os números de lançamentos nos quais o resultado obtido é
maior do que a média aritmética dos 50 lançamentos;
(c) determinar a percentagem de ocorrência da face seis do dado.
```

O que fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 50
int main() {
    int dado[MAX];
    int vetLancamentos[MAX];
    int p=0;
    float per = 0;
    float media_aritmetica = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &dado[i]);
        vetLancamentos[i] = dado[i];
        if (dado[i]==6) {
            p++;
        } else {
            printf("");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", vetLancamentos[i]);
        media_aritmetica+=(float)vetLancamentos[i]/MAX;
    }
    printf("\nLancamentos (maiores que a media):\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if (vetLancamentos[i]>media_aritmetica) {
            printf("%d ", vetLancamentos[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n6: %d ", p);
    per = (((float)p/MAX));
    printf("\nPercentagem: %f", per);

    return 0;
}
```

desculpa se soa uma pergunta inútil, é que não tenho certeza se está calculado da forma correta, agradeço a paciência.

ASSIM FICOU O CÓDIGO APÓS EDIÇÃO, OBRIGADO PELA AJUDA DE AMBOS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 6
int main() {

    int vetLancamentos[MAX];
    int p = 0; float soma = 0;
    float per = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &vetLancamentos[i]);
        soma += (float)vetLancamentos[i];
        if (vetLancamentos[i]==6) {
            p++;
        } else {
            printf("");
        }
    }

    printf("Media aritmetica: %f ", soma/(float)MAX);
    printf("\nLancamentos (maiores que a media):\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        if (vetLancamentos[i]>(soma/(float)MAX)) {
            printf("%d ", vetLancamentos[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n6: %d ", p);
    per = (((float)p/MAX)*100);
    printf("\nPercentagem: %f", per);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é só multiplicar por 100? `per = ((float) p / MAX) * 100` - de qualquer forma, dá pra simplificar um pouco: a variável `dado` é meio redundante, vc pode usar apenas o array de lançamentos, dá pra ir somando os valores no mesmo loop que lê (assim, vc usa a soma pra calcular a média depois), etc: https://ideone.com/XRvopH

Comment: obrigado pela dica, realmente percebi que dado[i] se torna redundante, agora o código está mais limpo, multipliquei por 100 e obtive a porcentagem aceitável, valeu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor maneira de saberes, é criares 3 ou 4 sequências de dados feitas por ti no qual tu sabes previamente a média e a percentagem de 6. Corres o teu código com essa sequência e verificas se o resultado é o mesmo...

Para facilitar, podes diminuir, temporariamente, o número de lançamentos para 10 ou 5... que à partida funciona da mesma maneira.

A minha análise do teu código sem testar indica que está bem. Notei que o array "dado" é inútil (pode ser uma simples variável), mas fora isso deve estar bem.